# awk - print $0 ignores OFS

Tags: awk

I want to output every Column / Field, but when I do it with the `$0` variable, it ignores the default `OFS` variable which is a single `space`, so the `:`'s still get printed.

Here is the command I tried:

```bash
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{print $0}'
```

Given this sample input:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I get this output from my command:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

But I want my output to look like this:

```bash
root x 0 0 root /root /bin/bash
daemon x 1 1 daemon /usr/sbin /usr/sbin/nologin
```

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: In order to re-evaluate `$0` with a new `OFS`, you need to modify at least one field - see the note at the bottom of [Changing the Contents of a Field](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html)

Comment: @steeldriver wow that seems weird. Do you know by any chance why this is the case?

Comment: @steeldriver : not really modify, but recalcultate.  $1=$1 suffices

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$0` represents the whole line, including input field separators.

You can cause it to be split and rejoined using output field separator simply by setting a field:

```
</etc/passwd  awk -F: '{$1=$1;print}'
```

(I changed to read directly from the file, rather than torturing a `cat` ;-)

This is documented in [Changing the Contents of a Field](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) section of the manual of the GNU implementation of `awk` (aka `gawk`):

> Finally, there are times when it is convenient to force `awk` to rebuild
> the entire record, using the current values of the fields and `OFS`. To
> do this, use the seemingly innocuous assignment:
>
> ```awk
> $1 = $1   # force record to be reconstituted
> print $0  # or whatever else with $0
> ```
>
> This forces `awk` to rebuild the record. It does help to add a comment,
> as we’ve shown here.

Comment: You don't even have to redirect the input file, btw - awk knows how to read files by itself: `awk -F: '{$1=$1;print}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: Since `awk`'s field splitting is rather naive (when using a single character as the field separator), and since the default output delimiter is a single space, the same result would be had via `tr : ' ' <file` or `sed 'y/:/ /' file`.

Comment: Interestingly `NF = NF`, too, rebuilds the record with new `OFS`.

Comment: @AdminBee,`awk` can't open arbitrary  file paths. It can't open a file called `-` or `foo=bar.txt`. Older versions of busybox awk would have problems with file paths starting with `-` here. The shell is able to open file by any path and if the files can't be opened, it skips running `awk` altogether (and in `<in awk... >out` avoids overwriting `out`) and can give you a more useful error message.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas while that's true, using `<in awk` robs you of the ability to use `FILENAME` inside the script and you can't do it like that for multiple input files (`awk '...' file1 file2` doesn't just become `<file1 <file2 awk '...'`) so it's a tradeoff. Since multiple input files and use of FILENAME are both common in awk scripts I personally haven't found it worthwhile to use `<file awk '...'` for just those cases where you don't have either of those considerations and then `awk '...' file(s)` for all the rest.

Comment: @EdMorton, *`awk '...' file1 file2` can become `<file1 <file2 awk '...'`* if your shell is zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for that info. That obviously still doesn't solve the problem for bash or other shells, nor does it populate FILENAME inside the awk script for any shell.

Comment: It just occurred to me you can't do `<file awk '...'` when calling awk from `find ... -exec` or `xargs` or even `awk '...' foo*` which are all common ways that awk gets called.

Comment: @EdMorton I though you `upvote` / `downvote` if you think the question itself is good, not the quality of the formulation of the question... :/

Comment: @EdMorton, with `find` you usually have at least `./` at the start of any path, which should work to remove most issues. (Sure, you could run `find *=* -exec awk '{print NF, var}' {}  \;` and get issues, but mostly one doesn't.)

Comment: @ilkkachu right, I'm saying `<file awk '...'` is a useful tool to apply if you run into a specific problem but since it has many common cases where you can't use it it's not worth using it by default vs just `awk '...' file`.

Comment: @Pixelbog I don't necessarily think so - the tooltip hints for the "Upvote" button e.g. says _"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"_, so the quality of the formulation is an important aspect.

Comment: @AdminBee hmmm. I don't agree with that at all, but well I can't argue with that^^ From now on I am gonna put a bit more effort into writing my questions :)

Comment: @Pixelbog Well, you know that you can always raise issues on the [site's meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/) if there is anything you want clarified or don't agree with ... That said, I actually _do_ think that a clear presentation should count [which I don't mean to critizice the quality of your question], since these questions are also here to benefit future readers, and unclear formulations often waste the time and motivation of contributors trying to help.

Comment: @AdminBee Oh no don't get me wrong^^ I agree with you, that it makes it better for future readers and the overall *stackexchange* site quality and that's important. But what I meant is, that the question itself is **way** more important. IMO it is `20% Quality` & `80% Question`. But seems I am alone with that opinion as obviously shown in this example :) *(And I know my question was terrible in quality. I had to edit it like 4 times^^)*

Comment: @Pixelbog, part of the issue is _figuring out what the question actually is_, and clear presentation is rather mandatory for that to be easily discoverable. And that comes already at the part where someone tries to answer the question, not only when those hypothetical future readers come around. I don't mean to comment on your question in particular, but in general.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah I absolutely agree on that. Maybe it's not `80 - 20`, maybe it's `60 - 40` or even `50 - 50`. I just think it should also be important how good the question is and not only the `research effort` or `the question is clear`

Answer (score 1):

The $0 field is just the line, with no parsing done. You'll need to loop over each field, making use of the NF variable (number of fields, determined by your FS):

`cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s ",$i}; printf "\n"};'`

Comment: That adds a blank at the end of the line, doesn't use `OFS`, and is hard-coding the value you hope `ORS` has, `\n`, instead of just using `ORS`. If you were going to use a loop for this it'd be `for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,OFS; print $NF` or similar.

Comment: Fair enough on the space char after the last field, but without a clearly defined spec, that's nit picking. Providing an example solution to "I want my output to look like this", was achieved. Too much ignorance comes from people who use SE as a copy/paste resource.